# Find the sids of Suppliers who supply every red or green part

Tags: relational-algebra

The database consists of Suppliers(sId,sName,address), Parts(pID,pName,color), and Catalog(sId,pId,cost). The solution to this question is given to be

[image]

However, this seems wrong to me since then we are actually looking for suppliers that supply every red and green part. Am I just interpreting the logic of the question wrong or is it worded incorrectly?

Comment: Please edit your question. It's not clear what you mean by "we are actually looking for"--is what follows your rephrasing of the title, or the query, or what? Also please *explain* why you think it's reasonable to interpret some English in a certain way. That includes your own English--do you mean "suppliers that supply every <red and green part>" or "suppliers who supply every red part and every green part? It's not clear what "red & green part" would mean--presumably, a part paired with red & with green in Parts.

Comment: The query doesn't match any reasonable interpretation of either English phrasing because it returns suppliers who supply *at least one part and* supply blah bah: normally if there are no parts of a certain kind then we would say *all* suppliers supply every such part, but the query in that case returns *no* suppliers. PS [Use text, not images/links, for text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Here, use names of symbols, names of operators, or google 'unicode sigma' or 'unicode join' (etc).

Answer (score 0):

your answer is correct . In Relational Algebra when ever we have to find sids,sname etc. and have the word 'every' in the question we use division method . In your question you have to find 'sids' which supply every red or green part. Now as 'color' is in "part" relation and sid is in "catalog" and "suppliers" relation but we can only connect part and catalog using pid and fortunately sid is in catalog so we will use these two relations form our relational algebra :

```
Πsid,pid (Catalog)/ Πpid σcolor=’red’ v color=’green’ (Parts)
```

Answer (score 0):

T1 <-- Πpid( σcolor=’RED’ (Parts) )

T2 <-- Πpid( σcolor=’GREEN’ (Parts) )

T3 <-- Πsid,pid( Catalog ) ÷ T1

T4 <-- Πsid,pid( Catalog ) ÷ T2

T5 <-- T3 U T4

T5 has the answer

this will give sids of supplier who supply all red or all green part

Hope this helps.